# Unable to call discovery.build('compute', 'v1', credentials=credentials) from GCE

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-api-python-client

On running the build command it is getting timed out.

```
from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
service = discovery.build('compute', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
```

I am running this on compute engine only with properly setting env. This was working earlier.
I am able to run `service = discovery.build('storage', 'v1', credentials=credentials)`
Error I am getting now

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 134, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 250, in build
    developerKey, num_retries=num_retries
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 316, in _retrieve_discovery_doc
    resp, content = req.execute(num_retries=num_retries)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 134, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 901, in execute
    headers=self.headers,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 204, in _retry_request
    raise exception
ssl.SSLError: ('The read operation timed out',)
```

Is there some issue with compute engine API?
Any lead will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known temporary issue. From https://status.cloud.google.com/

> Google's API Discovery Service GetRest (https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/pubsub/v1/rest) requests are hanging in the following regions: asia-northeast1, asia-northeast2, asia-northeast3, asia-southeast1, europe-west1,europe-west3, europe-west6, europe-west4, northamerica-northeast1,southamerica-east1,us-central1, us-east1, us-west1, us-west2, and us-west4.

> We are currently working to mitigate by rolling back a configuration change. Next update time is Thursday, 2020-10-08 07:00 US/Pacific.

Comment: Is it for compute too? I see pubsub link

Comment: How I was able to hit it from the cloudfunction which is us-west2?

Comment: " us-west1, us-west2, and " :)